# Grant a person permission to moderate all comments on a blog without giving them the ability to edit other peoples post

Tags: comments, user-roles, user-access

I'm trying to figure out how to create  a wordpress role that grants the user the ability to only moderate all comments (including for posts that aren't there own).  The only way I've been able to do this is by granting them the ability to edit other peoples posts, but I don't want to give them that much permission.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Justin Tadlocks Members Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) is a great start. Create a new role and give them the permission of `moderate_comments` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I already have that feature enable and assigned to people.  However they are only allowed to moderate comments on posts that they have made, and not on site-wide posts.

Comment: that's because you also have to allow them to `edit others post`